# VSCode hide lines that start with certain code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a lot of `if verbosity: print('Some feedback')` in my code, which is useful but also clutters the code itself. Is it possible to 'fold' these lines, based on the condition that the line starts with this specific bit of code? By folding I mean like you can do with certain blocks of code, by clicking the little down arrow next to the line number:
[image: Here a code block can be 'folded in' / hidden by clicking the little down arrow]

Comment: have a look at the **Explicit Folding** extension, it can do auto folding but you always see 1 line of the fold

Comment: maybe you can make these lines almost transparent (color identical to edit background) with extension **Highlight**

Comment: Thanks rioV8! **Highlight** works perfectly! Posted answer with credits to your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8)'s suggestion to use the [Highlight Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) and his implementation is working perfectly. In order to implement: insert the following in the User Settings (JSON):

```
    // Extension: Highlight
        "highlight.regexes": {
        
        // Grey out ``if (not) (self.){v|verbosity|verbose}:``-lines
        "(if( not)? ((self\\.)?(v|verbosity|verbose)).*)": {
            "color": "#808080"
        },
```

All credits go to [rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8)!

Comment: it can all be combined in `(if( not)?( self\\.)?v(erbos(e|ity)?)?:.*)`

Comment: in the first regex you have the `()` wrong, `if self\\.v:.*` will not get colored, in second regex you have `|)` that will catch the empty space => a lot of hits

Answer (score 0):

You can use native folding in convenient and straightforward way using multi cursor. If your file has recognized syntax and all content chunks you intend to be folded are in identifiable scopes (block) where you can safely select something inside or in initial line, all you need is

- *Select All Occurrences of Find Match* (`editor.action.selectHighlights`)
- *Fold* (`editor.fold`)
- *Unfold* (`editor.unfold`)

[image: Using commands to fold and unfold block containing word in poorly formatted JavaScript file.]

It works even for "plaintext" files, provided that structure is denoted by indentation levels:

[image: Folding indented blocks in plaintext file.]

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use this for lines starting with "logging." but it is not even searching for a simple "logging" or "logging\." in the JSON. Yet, "logging"logging\.(debug)" changes the format of "loggi" (but only in logging.debug) and "logging\.(info) changes it for "logg" (only in logging.info)

Regex works as expected in the vsCode Search function. Is there anything wrong with vsCode or What am I missing?

Comment: r0ck0 , in this subreddit, solved it: 

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/16sixea/comment/k2e5jif/?context=3

vsCode/Highlight extension needs to encompass all as a group `(all_your_regex_char_pattern)`.   - `^`, `&`... need a flag and go outside the group.
Also, it requires an additional escape char when that is used: `\\.`
Thank him